# concurrent relaying of data between multiple clients

Tags: go, concurrency

I am currently working on an application relaying data sent from a mobile phone via a server to a browser using WebSockets. I am writing the server in go and I have a one-to-one relation between the mobile phones and the browsers as shown by the following illustration.

[image: communication flow between mobile phone and server].

However, I want multiple sessions to work simultaneously.

I have read that go provides concurrency models that follow the principle "share memory by communicating" using goroutines and channels. I would prefer using the mentioned principle rather than locks using the `sync.Mutex` primitive.

Nevertheless, I have not been able to map this information to my issue and wanted to ask you if you could suggest a solution.

Comment: It's hard to help without any code to go by. Can you be more specific about what problem you're having implementing this?

Comment: look at `gorilla/websocket` chat example, its implemented as chat room, but can be modified to work one to one.

Comment: what exactly you want to share?

Comment: @Uvelichitel I simply want to relay messages from the mobile phone to the browser and vice-versa.

Comment: The OS from your server still has to route all the traffic through the one http server port.  So no parallelism there.  The go application has to read all the traffic from this port with a single goroutine.  If you are just looking  up the outgoing connection to use to echo the message, you may find it more efficient to do it all in one goroutine, then no channel or mutex is needed.  How to take advantage of multiple cores with web sockets when there is no real work to do on the server side is an interesting question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with using a mutex in Go. Here's a solution using a mutex.

Declare a map of endpoints. I assume that a string key is sufficient to identify an endpoint:

```
type endpoint struct {
    c *websocket.Conn
    sync.Mutex  // protects write to c
}

var (
   endpoints = map[string]*endpoint
   endpointsMu sync.Mutex   // protects endpoints
)

func addEndpoint(key string, c *websocket.Connection) {
   endpointsMu.Lock()
   endpoints[key] = &endpoint{c:c}
   endpointsMu.Unlock()
}

func removeEndpoint(key string) {
    endpointsMu.Lock()
    delete(endpoints, key)
    endpointsMu.Unlock()
}

func sendToEndpoint(key string, message []byte) error {
    endpointsMu.Lock()
    e := endpoints[key]
    endpointsMu.Unlock()
    if e === nil {
        return errors.New("no endpoint")
    }
    e.Lock()
    defer e.Unlock()
    return e.c.WriteMessage(websocket.TextMessage, message)
}
```

Add the connection to the map with `addEndpoint` when the client connects. Remove the connection from the map with `removeEndpoint` when closing the connection. Send messages to a named endpoint with `sendToEndpoint`.

The [Gorilla chat example](https://github.com/gorilla/websocket/tree/master/examples/chat) can be adapted to solve this problem.  Change the hub map to `connections map[string]*connection`, update channels to send a type with connection and key and change the broadcast loop to send to a single connection.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar to your problem, I needed multiple connections which each send data to each other through multiple servers.

I went with the [WAMP](http://wamp-proto.org) protocol

```
WAMP is an open standard WebSocket subprotocol that provides two application messaging patterns in one unified protocol:
Remote Procedure Calls + Publish & Subscribe.
```

You can also take a look at a project of mine which is written in go and uses the protocol at hand: [github.com/neutrinoapp/neutrino](https://github.com/neutrinoapp/neutrino)

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I don't think a further protocol will suit my needs. Also the client should run on Android and eventually iOS and Windows Phone, thus I want to use simple socket connections.

Comment: Well these are simple socket connections underneath.